# Windows 7 minimize/maximize shortcuts behave differently than buttons

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I love the new Win-up and Win-down shortcuts for maximize/minimize in windows 7. However, sometimes they behave differently than clicking the maximize/minimize buttons directly.

In programs that minimize to the tray, Win-down does not seem to send them to the tray. And in remote desktop, Win-up will maximize the window, but the maximize button will trigger full-screen mode.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Start-↓ sends Outlook to tray for me.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I can think of would be to use [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) to map the Win+Up and Win+Down directly to window maximize and minimize. Still keeps the same hotkeys, just changes their function slightly.

In fact, Lifehacker posted a script that simulates Windows 7 hotkey functionality [here](http://lifehacker.com/5133039/windows-7-shortcuts-enables-the-best-win7-shortcuts-in-xp-or-vista). You should be able to use that as a template to fix your issue (if nothing else).

Comment: Thanks, Cory. Strangely enough even this doesn't work. Maybe those programs have event handlers on the buttons that are bypassed by a direct call to minimize/maximize.

Answer (score 1):

For remote desktop, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> to switch the client in full screen, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+/-</kbd> will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Autohotkey script that Cory suggested. I could not put this in a comment, as they can not be in several lines:

```
#Up::WinMaximize, A    ; Assign a hotkey to maximize the active window 
#Down::WinMinimize, A  ; Assign a hotkey to minimize the active window
```

Give the votes to Cory, he gave the answer, I'm just refining it :-)